# Why does this output have decimals? Also, it is far from correct answer

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the sum of digits of 2^1000 in c++.

As you can see, the value of 2^1000 contains many zeroes and some digits, but even then the output of sum turns out to be in decimals.

My code is the following:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

main() {
  cout<<fixed;

  long double a=pow(2,1000),sum=0;

  cout<<"2^1000 is"<<a<<"\n";
  while(a) {
    sum+=fmod(a,10);
    a/=10;
  }

cout<<sum;
}
```

I used `fmod()` since the % operator is not overloaded for long double, I had never used `fmod()` earlier but used it as mentioned [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/).

I don't really think `fmod()` is doing any mistake here, so any suggestion why the output of sum is in decimals? Futher, the correct answer should be 1366.

Here is the sample output:

[image: sample execution]

Okay, so solved my problem by using this [Bigint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libbigint/) library!

Comment: Why not use an integer type like `long int`?

Comment: Small errors accumulate over 1000 iterations. http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: long int cant actually store 302 digit number, all it can do is 19..

Comment: You're right, you'll have to create your own type that can handle integers up to ~10^300.

Comment: actually , while practicing i did made a data type to store about 30 digits, and could expand it easily but overloading all operators is a tedious job..

Comment: @AbhinavAgarwal long double can't store such large number either. If long double on your target is 80-bit extended precision then it can only store ~19.2 digits. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Beta: I'm not sure if you really need that. Using a `std::vector<char> digits` I can easily write an iterative `multiply2` function, call that a thousand times in O(N log N) time, and then I can call `std::accumulate` directly. BCD may be primitive, but there are problems for which it's simple.

Comment: @MSalters: But then you *have* created a type that can handle integers up to ~10^300.

Comment: @Beta: It's a bit optimistic to call it an integer type when the only operation is `x <- x * 2`.

Comment: @MSalters: Hey, I didn't say it could handle integers very *deftly.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store `2^1000` in a single variable in C++. `2^1000` needs at least 1000 bits to be stored in binary, no variable of primitive type is long enough. So the first printed result is already wrong, remember that no power of 2 contains an ending 0 (`2*2=4`, `4*2=8`, `8*2=16`, `6*2=2`). Then you cannot rely on the result of `fmod`.

`2^1000=10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376`

Comment: okay.. Then, any other suggestions (like some algorithm) to do this in c++ other than making my own data type.

Comment: There is many method to compute reminders of huge powers. But for this one, it is not hard, hints for it are in my answer.